# Duplicate data of sub report at Details section in main Report

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, duplicate-data, subreport, subreports

Please help me !
I have a problem in Crystal Report at visual studio::

I have 2 sub reports within the main report , and I put them at main Details section , when i run the report , the sub reports duplicated many times ..

thanks for solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing subreports within the details section will reproduce the subreport each time the Details section is printed.

If you want the subreport only once; you will need to ensure that there is only one detail line printed on the main report.  Or you could place the subreports in a header/footer.

A more detailed answer will require more detailed information about your report.

Comment: Well, I put them at header and every thing is good .. thanks to you :) .

Answer (score 0):

Put subreports in group section in main report..and don't pust subreport in detail section
 this will solve your issue...

Answer (score 0):

Sub report duplicates problem in report header.
Let say, you have field Employee Name in your report header.
That name comes form dataset and dataset has 5 rows, each row repeats same employee name.
So your sub report in detail section will repeats 5 times.
Fix your header data first and duplicates should go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print subreport in detail section one time,
just add header section, then check underlay following section option in section expert,then place subreport where you want to print.